# In Unity3D, PerformanceCounter always returns 0

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, performance-testing, performancecounter

This has been a frequently asked question and I've tried solutions prescribed in other questions which could be applicable for my scenario (like the initial value being expected to be 0, repeatedly calling `NextValue()` to allow the `PerformanceCounter` to gather more data, etc.).

Now I'm wondering if there's a prescribed way of using the class for **Unity** which is stopping me from making it work.

Testing on Android devices and the Editor, the `GetCpuUsage()` and `GetRamUsage()` methods always print out 0, even though these functions are essentially called every frame.

**How can I make `PerformanceCounter` work in Unity?** Alternatively, if this is a known issue, are there alternative solutions I can do to produce the same desired result of displaying onscreen the memory and/or CPU usage of the app?

Code snippet:

```
public class PerformanceCounterDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PerformanceCounter _cpuCounter;
    private PerformanceCounter _ramCounter;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text _cpuCounterText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text _ramCounterText;

    void Start()
    {
        _cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        _ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", "_Total");
        _cpuCounterText.text = GetCpuUsage();
        _ramCounterText.text = GetRamUsage();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _cpuCounterText.text = GetCpuUsage();
        _ramCounterText.text = GetRamUsage();
    }

    public string GetCpuUsage()
    {
        try
        {
            return "CPU: " + _cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
        }
        catch (Exception eh)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Cannot get infomation about this PC's CPU");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public string GetRamUsage()
    {
        try
        {
            return "RAM: " + _ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";
        }
        catch (Exception eh)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Cannot get infomation about this PC's RAM");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/506736/measure-cpu-and-memory-load-in-code.html) out?

Comment: Hi @Hristo , yes indeed. That was my first step towards solving my problem. The issue now is that the `PerformanceCounter` class isn't working as expected and I'm unsure why.

Comment: Just making sure. So you have included the complete .NET 2.0 libraries (not the subset)?

Comment: @Hristo Yes, I have. And it's compiling correctly.

Comment: I think the first param needs to be "Processor" not "Process"